# Can I ask a question with my answers to select best one

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've gathered two or more answers to my own question that I haven't asked here in this community. My question is, can I ask my questions with the answers below it to find the best one after votes or maybe make an answer out of them then accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to ask your question and provide the two answers you mentioned as possible solutions. Then ask the community what they think would be the best solution and why. And maybe even ask if they might know of an even better solution.

If other people agree with the answer provided by someone else, they'll upvote it. This will be a good indication for you that that might be the way to go.